# Given these variables, how would I calculate the time when this airplane crosses over my position or 10,000 meters in a circle around it?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm in the last, most difficult step of making an automated system to warn me well before an airplane crosses over the sky where I live, which has become a real annoyance in recent years as the entire area shakes from the vibrations.

I know these seemingly relevant variables:

1. My GPS position (WGS-84 longitude/latitude).
2. The current time as a Unix timestamp.
3. The air plane's GPS position (WGS-84 longitude/latitude).
4. The air plane's "true track" direction in decimal degrees clockwise from north (north=0°).
5. The air plane's "velocity" (speed, I assume that means) in m/s.
6. The number of meters between the air plane's position and my own. (I calculate this with the "Vincenty" formula, which hopefully is accurate enough.)

It's quite possible that the airplane will never come anywhere close to me. (For example, it could be heading in a completely different direction and currently be outside of the 10,000 meter "sphere" around me.)

I'm trying to construct an formula/expression which would tell me the Unix timestamp when this airplane (if ever) enters into the 10,000-meter sphere around my position, or the number of seconds left until this occurs. The reason I mention Unix timestamp is that this is an integer and thus "calculation friendly".

Maybe this is very basic math to you math experts, but to me, it's hopelessly difficult. However, once I see the expression/formula, it will probably make sense to me. I half-remember even solving (or trying to solve...) similar problems way back in my school years, probably thinking that I would never need this...